# Initialize local datastore exception : No API environment is registered for this thread

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to initialize my local data store with some data using a
regular Java program (I do not want to start the Development Server
and call a service/servlet), and I'm getting the following exception

EXCEPTION :

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: No API environment is registered for this thread.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppId(DatastoreApiHelper.java:108)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppIdNamespace(DatastoreApiHelper.java:118)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key.(Key.java:104)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key.(Key.java:88)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key.(Key.java:84)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity.(Entity.java:122)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity.(Entity.java:103)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreFieldManager.(DatastoreFieldManager.java:187)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertPreProcess(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:338)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjects(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:251)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:240)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:3185)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.makePersistent(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:3161)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1298)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1175)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:669)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:694)
    at com.stuff.server.GreetingServiceImpl.saveContact(GreetingServiceImpl.java:25)
    at com.stuff.server.TestCase.testServerCallBack(TestCase.java:18)
    at com.stuff.server.TestCase.main(TestCase.java:13)`

TestCase.java

`public class TestCase {
    static GreetingServiceImpl greetingServiceImpl = new GreetingServiceImpl();`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    testServerCallBack();//line9
}

private static void testServerCallBack() {
    Contacts contacts = new Contacts("this is", "awesome");
    greetingServiceImpl.saveContact(contacts);//line:14
}
```

}

greeting.....impl.java

`public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        GreetingService {`

```
public String greetServer(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return "";
}

@Override
public void saveContact(Contacts contacts) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    pm.makePersistent(contacts); //line:20
    pm.close();
}
```

}

Is there a way to do this? How?

Comment: I get the same error while running a TimerTask any ideas .please note that iam not using the cron configuration of the GAE

Answer (score 8):

Google provides a helper class that does exactly what you want - runs just enough code to work with the database, without launching the whole dev server. See the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting.html

Comment: well.. I am not sure this is helpful. I have been stuck on this for awhile and the helper class seems to create a fake / new database. So I can't figure out a way to read data that is already in the local database

Answer (score 3):

You have to setup a test Datastore Service for current thread. Basically you can do this:

```
private static void testServerCallBack() {
    LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
        new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());
    helper.setUp();
    Contacts contacts = new Contacts("this is", "awesome");
    greetingServiceImpl.saveContact(contacts);//line:14
}
```

That will initialize Database Service (a fake, for testing only) for *this method only*.

Or *better* you can do:

```
private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
  new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

@Before
public void setUp() {
   helper.setUp();
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
   helper.tearDown();
}
```

So Database Service will work from all test methods.

Notice that if you're using different threads to access db, then you'll get a separate database for each thread. That's not what you want most likely. I mean `helper.setUp()` do setup a new separate Database Service for current thread, and all data stored into this db will be accessible only from current thread.

See more details at: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting.html

Comment: Can I access Datastore locally through [RemoteApi](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/remoteapi)

Answer (score 2):

Just add those 3 libs (appart of the test one) to your classpath:

```
${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-api.jar
${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-api-labs.jar
${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-api-stubs.jar
```

This should fix the problem.