# Adding JAR files to your testing classpath:

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

Am performing a junit test on one of my methods in a class in android. and according to the info at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting.html  i should add the libraries below to my classpath.

```
${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-api.jar
${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-api-labs.jar
${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-api-stubs.jar
```

My question is, where in u.s should i get this libraries and how should i add them? am using android studio running on ubuntu 15 64bit.

am fairly new in android and GAE things!

**what i have tried**
this is what i have added to my modlue's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:1.8.2'
testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:1.8.2'
testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:1.8.2'
testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-tools-sdk:1.8.2'
testCompile 'org.json:json:20141113'
}
```

**When i try to run my junit test class. this is what am getting**

```
com.googlecode.objectify.SaveException: Error saving 
com.top.ash.backend.entities.Ameggedon@589b3632: No API environment is registered for this thread.

com.googlecode.objectify.impl.EntityMetadata.save(EntityMetadata.java:95)
 at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.WriteEngine.save(WriteEngine.java:75)
  at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.SaverImpl.entities(SaverImpl.java:60)
  at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.SaverImpl.entity(SaverImpl.java:35)

org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: No API environment is registered for this thread.
```

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** *I know nothing about GAE, but here is how you can add jars from folder to test classpath.*

Create a new folder in the same directory as `libs` folder (in this picture it is called `testlibs`). In this directory you should put those jars.

[image: Folder]

Now, add to the `build.gradle` of the module (not of the project), inside `dependencies` block:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testCompile fileTree(dir: 'testlibs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Now in your tests (Junit, not instrumentation) you could use the methods from the jar.

Comment: how can i get those .jar files after the have been downloaded when syncing my project? in which folder are they stored?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405211/initialize-local-datastore-exception-no-api-environment-is-registered-for-this

Comment: how do i add those .jar files. am i doing the right way by including them in my module's gradle file? since its from this module that am creating a test class.

Comment: You are adding the jars OK. just follow [Google tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting?csw=1).

Comment: am following it but this is what am getting when i run my test ``java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalRpcService: Provider com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalCloudDatastoreV1Service could not be instantiated
``

Comment: Sorry then, I'm not familiar with GAE.

Comment: it was very good that you tried to help. keep up the spirit brother